# Perform search based on seperate table data in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a table which looks like this:

```
deals
id     vendorid     name
1      52           '25% Off'
2      34           '10% Off'
```

-

```
vendors
id     name
52     'Walmart'
34     'Home Depot'
```

I'm trying to do a search of the database that also searches based on the vendor id.

I was able to do this to get the vendor data in the query:

```
SELECT *,
(SELECT json_agg(vendors.*) FROM vendors WHERE deals.vendorid = vendors.id) as vendor
FROM deals
```

Now I want to add a search to it, here is something I tried

```
SELECT *,
(SELECT json_agg(vendors.*) FROM vendors WHERE deals.vendorid = vendors.id) as vendor
FROM deals
WHERE vendor.name ILIKE '%wal%'
```

In the above example the user would be starting a search for `walmart` however it says that the vendor.name column does not exist, what would the correct way to do this be?

The output I'm expecting from the above query is:

```
[
 {
   id: 1,
   vendorid: 52,
   name: '25% Off',
   vendor: [
      {
        id: 52,
        name: 'Walmart'
      }
   ]
 }
]
```

Comment: Your `vendor` query is not returning a column named `name`, so you can't use it in the query. Why not use it on the inside query? `WHERE deals.vendorid = vendors.id AND vendors.name ILIKE '%wal%')...`

Comment: I'm trying to get a list of the deals, the json_agg function is attaching the vendor data to the deal so that I can output it without a seperate query for each deal.

Comment: OK, but you do understand that `vendor.name` does not exist because you aren't returning that column, right?

Comment: Yes I get that, I don't know what the workaround is

Comment: what is the output you are expecting. This would help to clarify the question

Comment: The workaround is to use the JSON notation to get the value using the key: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html

Comment: @JulioOjeda Ok I added the desired output

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it done by using this.

```
SELECT 
      *,
      (SELECT json_agg(vendors.*) FROM vendors WHERE deals.vendorid = vendors.id) as vendor
    FROM 
      deals
    where (SELECT json_agg(vendors.*) FROM vendors WHERE deals.vendorid = vendors.id).name ILIKE '%wal%'
```

It's pretty ugly but get the work done. I am not really familiar with postgree but you can store it in a variable somehow.

Comment: This works great, and is really fast, yeah I wonder if there is a way to condense it

Answer (score 1):

The query you need

```
drop table if exists deals;
drop table if exists vendors;

create table if not exists deals(
  id serial, 
  vendorid int not null, 
  name varchar not null
); 

create table if not exists vendors(
  id serial,
  name varchar not null
);

insert into deals values 
(1,52,'25% off'), 
(2,34,'10% off');

insert into vendors values 
(52,'Walmart'),
(34,'Home Depot');


select 
    d.id,
    d.vendorid,
    v.name,
    json_agg(v.*)
from 
    vendors v 
left join 
    deals d on d.vendorid = v.id
where 
    --v.id=52 and
    v.name ILIKE '%wal%'
group by 
    d.id,
    d.vendorid,
    v.name;
```

If you are running a 9.3+ version of postgres, you can use a great feature provided by postgres : [the full text search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/textsearch.html)

check how it works [here](http://rachbelaid.com/postgres-full-text-search-is-good-enough/)

Enjoy postgres power.

Comment: How would I use it with data from another table in this scenario? The documentation doesn't provide an example of this.

Comment: to use the data from another table simply join your tables since you have a link (vendorid) between the tables. I edited my answer to add the query you were looking for. For a full text search implementation you will have to change the where clause. I can draft something if it is something you want to use.